# jquery validating special characters

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

using jquery,
on sublit Need to validate textbox value and throw error if it contains alphabets, special characters or digits less than 20

code:

```
   <input type="text" class="input-text-bx" id="actual" value="">
          <input type="submit" id="real" value="submit"/>
```

I have tried with jquery 1.3 without clicking submit button. I need latest one with $ on submit.

```
   Query(function(){

            jQuery('.input-text-bx').validate({
                expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
                message: "Please enter  a valid number"
            });
        jQuery('.input-text-bx').validate({
                expression: "if (VAL.match(/^[0-9]*$/)) return true; else return false;",
                message: "Actual card can only be in numbers"
            });
            jQuery('.input-text-bx').validate({
                expression: "if ((VAL.length >=16) )return true; else return false;",
                message: "The card number should be 16-20 digits"
            });
});
```

Comment: (What) have you tried?

Comment: Validate when? On form submit, on blur, or...? What do you mean by "throw error"? It might be clearer if you spell out what would be considered valid; "digits less than 20" is open to several interpretations.

Comment: There is no such thing as `.validate()` in jQuery unless you're using the [jQuery Validate plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).  See the documentation:  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onblur` event on the inputs

```
jQuery('.input-text-bx').bind('onblur', function(){ // Validation Here });
```

and in the function do your check on the length (>16 & <20). also you can match the RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

The `.validate()` in your code (and the [jquery-validate](/questions/tagged/jquery-validate) tag) indicates your attempt to use [the jQuery Validate plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).  Otherwise, there is no such thing as `.validate()` in jQuery without it.

```
<input type="text" class="input-text-bx" id="actual" value="">

jQuery('.input-text-bx').validate({
     expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
     message: "Please enter  a valid number"
});
```

1)  You *absolutely cannot* attach `.validate()` to any element other than a `<form></form>` element.  There is no workaround for this.

2)  There is no such `.validate()` option called `expression`.  If you need to write a custom method or rule, you would have to use [the plugin's built-in `addMethod` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage).

---

Try using the plugin like this instead.  (all `input` elements must have a `name` attribute for this plugin to work properly)

**HTML**:

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" class="input-text-bx" name="actual" id="actual" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            actual: {
                required: true,       // required field
                number: true,         // must be a number
                rangelength: [16, 20] // must be between 16 and 20 digits
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/NvREa/**

**Documentation:  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation**

Comment: what validate plugin do I need to use to implement it? How to check for special characters?

Comment: @user2194155, you've tagged the question with the "jQuery Validate" plugin and you're attempting to use `.validate()` so I thought you already had it installed.  Follow the examples and documentation in my answer.  Also here:  http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/